# Packages are not supported when using the legacy build system, but the current workspace has it enabled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, atlassian-sourcetree

I shot the project through sourceTree and I am trying to open it on Xcode. While I can run it on the master branch without any problem, I get the following error on the develop branch -> "Packages are not supported when using the legacy build system, but the current workspace has it enabled."

I searched for a long time solution on google with this error text. I made many trials. However, I could not solve the error and progress is preventing. Please can you help me save my time?
 
Here are the methods I tried;
- I downloaded and use the most current version of Xcode from the AppStore. I downloaded and installed Xcode 11.1 because it might be related to the version, but the problem was not solved.
- "File" -> I tried to change Legacy Build System or New Build System in "Workspace Settings" but the problem is not solved.
- I tried Pod install, Pod deintegrated, Pod update but the problem is not solved.
- I came to the project directory and tried the suggested code, but the problem is not solved. -> "xcodebuild -workspace Foo.xcworkspace -scheme Bar -configuration Release -archivePath /path/to/Foo.xcarchive clean archive -UseModernBuildSystem = NO"
-I shot the project again and again but the problem was not solved again.
-The modules added to the project are loading and I can see the inside. It may not be a problem from here. Because my other 2 friends tried to retake the project and tried to build the project in different branches without any problems. His projects are working.

I'm in a deadlock right now. My time has been wasted for days. Please help me I can not find a solution.
Thank you, I wish you good work.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61246107/165260

Comment: Did you find a solution on it?

Comment: If someone was as dumb as me: I opened xcodeproj file instead of xcworkspace, and got this error. Finally I've catched my dumbness, opened xcworkspace, and the error has gone.