# flutter dosn't run on ios

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to run my flutter code on ios but I am facing exit during running or building the app. the code is building fine in android however on ios I can't build it.
I tried to google on the issue but I am not finding yet the answer.

I found suggestion to change the platform iso target to 9.0.
it did fix the pod install but not yet able to run my flutter

here is what I got log from command `flutter run --verbose`

```
[   +5 ms] Found plugin firebase_auth at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.14.0+5/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+9/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin flutter_facebook_login at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_facebook_login-3.0.0/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.6/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin flutter_qr_reader at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_qr_reader-1.0.3/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin flutter_secure_storage at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_secure_storage-3.3.2/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin fluttertoast at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin google_sign_in at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-4.0.11/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin image_picker at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.4/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin libphonenumber at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/libphonenumber-1.0.1/
[   +7 ms] Found plugin path_provider at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.5/
[        ] Found plugin path_provider_macos at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_macos-0.0.4/
[   +2 ms] Found plugin permission_handler at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-3.3.0/
[   +6 ms] Found plugin share at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share-0.6.3+1/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.4+3/
[   +6 ms] Found plugin sqflite at /Users/ainnaaa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.1.7+2/
[ +390 ms] Generating /Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[ +106 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
[   +7 ms] /Users/ainnaaa/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart /Users/ainnaaa/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot
--sdk-root /Users/ainnaaa/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names
-Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true --output-dill /var/folders/y9/d10nl1n11msg831yf6c182jh0000gq/T/flutter_tool.cuyj0b/app.dill --packages
/Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/.packages -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts
--track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build/cache.dill
[  +35 ms] executing: /usr/bin/plutil -convert json -o - /Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/Runner/Info.plist
[  +59 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/plutil -convert json -o - /Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/Runner/Info.plist
[        ]
{"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrien
tationLandscapeRight"],"CFBundleIdentifier":"$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)","CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion":"6.0","UIMainStoryboardFile":"Main","CFBundleVersion":"$(FLUTTER_B
UILD_NUMBER)","UILaunchStoryboardName":"LaunchScreen","CFBundleExecutable":"$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)","LSRequiresIPhoneOS":true,"FacebookDisplayName":"Myanmar
app","UISupportedInterfaceOrientations":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],"CFBundleShortVersion
String":"$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)","UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance":false,"CFBundleURLTypes":[{"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor","CFBundleURLSchemes":["com.googleuserconten
t.apps.933819820088-iiufg7giuoksfdbh3rs044ftr0jk62g1","fb843554882793993"]}],"CFBundleSignature":"????","CFBundlePackageType":"APPL","FacebookAppID":"843554882793993","CFBun
dleDevelopmentRegion":"$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)","LSApplicationQueriesSchemes":["fbapi","fb-messenger-share-api","fbauth2","fbshareextension"],"CFBundleName":"mymyanmar_mobil
e"}
⣽[  +16 ms] executing: [/Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/] /usr/bin/xcodebuild -project
/Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/Runner.xcodeproj -target Runner -showBuildSettings
[        ] executing: [/Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/] /usr/bin/xcodebuild -project
/Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/Runner.xcodeproj -target Runner -showBuildSettings
[  +13 ms] <- compile package:mymyanmar_mobile/main.dart

(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)⣷[+33405 ms] Command line invocation:
                         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/Runner.xcodeproj -target Runner
                         -showBuildSettings


                     xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
                       Packages are not supported when using legacy build locations, but the current project has them enabled.
[   +2 ms] Unexpected failure to get the build settings: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
           Command line invocation:
               /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/Runner.xcodeproj -target Runner
               -showBuildSettings


           xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
             Packages are not supported when using legacy build locations, but the current project has them enabled.
             Command: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/Runner.xcodeproj -target Runner -showBuildSettings.
[  +41 ms] Building Runner.app for 14036E6B-6FE4-4767-B11D-8DC1746122C8.
[  +59 ms] Xcode workspace settings not found, skipping migration
[   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/ainnaaa/Documents/mymyanmar_mobile/ios/] /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
[  +60 ms] executing: script /dev/null /usr/bin/log stream --style syslog --predicate processImagePath CONTAINS "14036E6B-6FE4-4767-B11D-8DC1746122C8"
[ +462 ms] [DEVICE LOG] Filtering the log data using "processImagePath CONTAINS "14036E6B-6FE4-4767-B11D-8DC1746122C8""
[+11716 ms] Command line invocation:
                         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list


                     xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
                       Packages are not supported when using legacy build locations, but the current project has them enabled.
[   +1 ms] ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
           Command line invocation:
               /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list


           xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
             Packages are not supported when using legacy build locations, but the current project has them enabled.
             Command: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
[  +12 ms] "flutter run" took 54,494ms.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
#1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:569:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:722:18)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
#11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#18     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
#19     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
#20     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#21     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
#22     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
#23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#25     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is related to a bug in Xcode. Please open xcode directly and run the project from there.
For further help look at these useful links:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51632#issuecomment-592547201

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44811#issuecomment-553557378

Regards.

Comment: thanks, now I am trying using xcode and I find this issue `Module 'connectivity' not found`

Comment: @Saf Stackoverflow is a community to help developers when they are stuck. If you had searched a bit by yourself, you would have found:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42887#issuecomment-543348802

Comment: I am developer but just new to flutter. I am not even using connectivity package in Pubspec.yaml

Comment: @Saf there is a possibility that there are nested dependencies, i.e one of your dependencies uses Connectivity. In that case you will have to look into the dependencies you are using and try to use a fixed and stable version of that...